# .NET Core on RHEL 5 and RHEL 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, rhel, rhel6, rhel5

I developed a USB driver (CDC class) DLL for windows in .NET
Looks like I need to develop the same driver in Linux as well. The target system is running  RHEL 5 and above.

From the Microsoft documentation it is clear that on RHEL 7 and 8 I can leverage the .NET Core
Is it possible to use .NET Core on RHEL 5 and RHEL 6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-rhel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core is not supported on RHEL 5 at all. Not by Red Hat and not by Microsoft. You can't run .NET applications there.

.NET Core is supported on RHEL 6 by Microsoft, but there are some gotchas and installation isn't as easy as it could be. [This document includes installation steps for .NET Core and its dependencies on RHEL 6](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/build-and-install-rhel6-prerequisites.md).

.NET Core is fully supported on RHEL 7 and RHEL 8, both by Microsoft and Red Hat.

---

USB drivers are implemented very differently between Windows and Linux. Even ignoring older RHEL versions, do you have any idea if your driver will work on Linux at all? .NET Core on Linux, for example, doesn't support C/C++. Any P/Invoke calls you make to `kernel32.dll` for example, will not work on Linux either. Is your driver actually cross-platform?

Comment: Right now it is not cross platform. I am using the P/invoke functions. And since I need to support RHEL 5, 7 and Windows 7 and 10. I need to develop c/c++ drivers for different OS I believe. Thanks for the pointers Omajid. One last question though. Do you have any pointers for USB drivers on Linux.